# Two dynamicly sized divs side by side - second div determines size of second

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs side by side. First div has a random len text and second one has random number of divs inside.

I need these two divs to fill all space of their wrapper and I need first div starting to overflow text when the second one gets wider enough. The point of this is that when my first div narrows I can use [jquery-textfill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill/) to a adapt font-size of text so it can be fit inside.

Here is full example which has buttons to refresh random text and append square in wrapper.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by3mf77s/3/)

here is my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
#wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left{
  float:left;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square{
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float:right;
}
```

regards teamol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left{
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by3mf77s/6/)